# NoneType in QWebFrame Object childFrames() List

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4

I am trying to access a child frame inside a web page using python qt webkit.

The childFrames() result an empty list with NoneType in front of the list, how do I go directly to the second entity since I can't use fr.childFrames()[1][1] : It will throw  TypeError: 'QWebFrame' object does not support indexing.

These are part of the code:

```
fr = self.page().mainFrame().childFrames()
for f in fr:
    print f.frameName()
```

will output the frame title of each frame, but if :

```
fr = self.page().mainFrame().childFrames()
print fr
```

will output

```
[]
[<PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebFrame object at 0x14a1200>, <PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebFrame object at 0x14a1290>, <PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebFrame object at 0x14a1320>, <PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebFrame object at 0x14a13b0>]
```

If I go directly like this :

```
print fr[1].frameName()
```

Will throw IndexError first (The list with no content), and then will give me the title of the frame from the second list.

Is this an expected behaviour? if so, how do I get directly to the frames in the second list.

Answer (score 0):

Your output seems to be two lists - the first is empty, the second contains QWebFrames.

What does `print fr[1][0].frameName()` give you? It should return the frame name for `<PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebFrame object at 0x14a1200>`.

Comment: That's the problem, it is two lists, if I go with print type(fr) it will print two lines <type 'list'>. If I go with fr[1][0].frameName() it will throw error : TypeError: 'QWebFrame' object does not support indexing. If I make another loop like this; i = 0 for f in fr: ft.append(f) print i, f i=i+1 it will show me 0 - 3 excactly 4 items inside the list, it ignores the empty list and go to the list with content.